# MongoDB $lookup with nested object with nested array

Tags: mongodb

I have 2 collections.

*cases*

```
_id: ObjectId.
name: string.
info: {
    [here can be many different fields with diff types]
    relatedEntities: [
        { role: string;
          id: ObjectId;
        } <--- here can be a lot of entities
    ]
}
```

*entities*

```
_id: ObjectId.
type: string,
name: string,
info: {
    [here can be many different fields with diff types]
}
```

I need to retrieve all cases and for each case.info.entities object I need to have field **data** which will equal to entity document ( case.info.entities.id === entity_id)

*Example what I need to have*

```
_id: ObjectId.
name: string.
info: {
    [here can be many different fields with diff types]
    entities: [
        { role: string;
          id: ObjectId;
          data: {
            _id: ObjectId.
            type: string,
            name: string,
            info: {
              [here can be many different fields with diff types]
            }
          }
        } <--- here can be a lot of entities
    ]
}
```

How to do it in a proper way?

At the moment I implemented this is that way:

```
    { $unwind: "$info.relatedEntities" },
    { $lookup: {
            "from": "entities",
            "localField": "info.relatedEntities.entity",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "info.relatedEntities.entityObject"
        }},
    { $group: {
        "_id": "$_id",
         "templateType":{$first: "$templateType"},
          "info":{$first: "$info"},
          "relatedEntities": {
                $push: "$info.relatedEntities"
            }
        }}
```

It's working, but required additional parsing when data is retrieved, but I'd like to do it without workarounds..

Comment: can you update the question with a query, what have you tried..?

Comment: Can update with some data..?you updated question with diff model and query.?relatedEntities is not in model..but in query..? "info.relatedEntities" is missing in model you updated.

Comment: @the_mahasagar, it was mistake in my cases model, I've just updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done almost everything. Based on your query and model I have given below query (Field names might be different). Hope it helps.

```
db.cases.aggregate([
{ $unwind: '$info.relatedEntities' },
{ $lookup: {
        from: 'entities',
        localField: 'info.relatedEntities.entity',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'info.relatedEntities.entityObject'
    }
},
{ $group: {
    _id: {
        _id : '$_id',
        templateType : '$templateType',
        name : '$name',
        info :  {
            address : "$info.address",
        }
    },
    'relatedEntities': {
        $push: {
             role : '$info.relatedEntities.role',
             entity : '$info.relatedEntities.entity',
             data : { $arrayElemAt: [ '$info.relatedEntities.entityObject', 0 ] }
        }
    }
  }
},
{
  $project : {
     _id : '$_id._id',
     name : '$_id.name',
     templateType : '$_id.templateType',
     info : {
        address : '$_id.info.address',
        entities : '$relatedEntities'
     }
    }
  }
]).pretty()
```